# Textarea hashtag highlight is applied to the wrong position after the first line

Tags: javascript, regex

When I am going to newline and starting hashtag there from the beginning of that line, highlighter is applying color to the previous line.

```
  <style>
        #input{
            color: transparent;
        }
        #input b{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: transparent;
            background-color: #9aceff;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #t{
          background-color: transparent;            
        }
    </style>
```

```
<textarea id="t" style="width: 342px; height: 92px; resize: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1; border: 1px solid #212;font-family: arial; padding: 20px; margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">
</textarea>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #212; font-family: arial; padding: 20px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 12px;" id="input">

</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#t').on('input keyup', function() {
       var str = $(this).val();       
       str = str.replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');        
       str = str.replace(/(?:\s|^)#([^0-9\W\s][a-zA-z0-9]*)/g, ' <b>#$1</b>');       
       str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');       
       $('#input').html(str);
   });
});
</script>
```

Here is my jsfiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/n78ehusq/).

Comment: The problem is likely with your regexes. I've added the tag to the question and edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I know but i cant figure it out and thanks for the perfect editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing here is that your regex is replacing newline characters with a space before the final replacement of newline characters by `<br />` elements occurs.

As a result, in cases where your hashed string is preceded by a newline, the highlight will appear on the previous line, rather than correctly being placed on the same line as the hashed string.

A quick fix to this is to swap the last two string replacements, and add a space after the `<br />` to avoid it being included in the hashed string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#t').on('input keyup', function() {
       var str = $(this).val();       
       str = str.replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
       str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '<br /> ');
       str = str.replace(/(?:\s|^)#([^0-9\W\s][a-zA-z0-9]*)/g, ' <b>#$1</b>');       
       $('#input').html(str);
   });
});
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n78ehusq/1/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, this helps. Thanks. :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could give you a hand.